# Cassandra only returns some rows of a column family

Tags: cassandra, cql3, import-from-csv

I have the following column family in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE tese.airplane_max_delay (
airplane_manufacturer text,
airplane_model text,
year int,
tailnumber text,
airplane_engine text,
airtime int,
arrdelay int,
cod uuid,
depdelay int,
description_carrier text,
distance int,
month int,
uniquecarrier text,
PRIMARY KEY ((airplane_manufacturer, airplane_model), year, tailnumber)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (year DESC, tailnumber DESC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

I import to this column family a csv file with 10 million records by COPY command.

when I try to query the data only 6629 lines are returned. The query should return 10 million lines.
Why does this happen? How can I change this?

Comment: What's the copy command you run?

Comment: It's also important to note that Cassandra PRIMARY KEYs are unique.  So of your 10 million records, if any share the same manufacturer/model/year/tailnumber combination, they will all write to the same row (and the last write "wins").

Comment: you are correct Aaron. I did not realize that the combination of primary key was not unique. Thanks

Comment: Please mark this question as solved